# Get Menu Items from REST API (React)

Tags: menus, block-editor, rest-api

I'm a bit rusty on the WordPress since version 5.9 but I can see that they've added Menus to the REST API and we can use new get methods in: `wp.data.select("core")`.

I'm trying to get the **menu items** from a menu called 'legal', which has the ID 449. How do we use these new functions to get those menu items for use in custom blocks?

### .getMenu(449)

Returns the legal menu object not including any menu items/links ???

```
{
    "id": 449,
    "description": "",
    "name": "Legal",
    "slug": "legal",
    "meta": [],
    "locations": [
        "legal_menu"
    ],
    "auto_add": false,
    "_links": {
        "self": [
            {
                "href": "http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/menus/449"
            }
        ],
        "collection": [
            {
                "href": "http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/menus"
            }
        ],
        "about": [
            {
                "href": "http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/taxonomies/nav_menu"
            }
        ],
        "wp:post_type": [
            {
                "href": "http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/menu-items?menus=449"
            }
        ],
        "wp:menu-location": [
            {
                "embeddable": true,
                "href": "http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/menu-locations/legal_menu"
            }
        ],
        "curies": [
            {
                "name": "wp",
                "href": "https://api.w.org/{rel}",
                "templated": true
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

### .getMenuItem()

No idea how to use this ??

### .getMenuItems()

No idea how to use this ??

Can anyone help to fill in the gaps please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getMenu()` fetches data from the `GET /wp/v2/menus/<id>` endpoint, whereas `getMenuItem()` fetches data from the `GET /wp/v2/menu-items/<id>` endpoint, but they have the same usage syntax, where you just need to pass the ID of a menu or menu item.

As for `getMenuItems()` and another function you can use — `getMenus()`, the endpoints are `GET /wp/v2/menu-items` (for fetching *menu items*) and `GET /wp/v2/menus` (for fetching *menus*), respectively. These functions have the same syntax, where you can pass an object containing the arguments accepted by their respective REST API endpoint, but these arguments are *optional* and when the function is called without any arguments specified (e.g. `getMenuItems()`), all menu items or menus will be returned.

- You can find the list of accepted arguments by visiting `<your site URL>/wp-json/wp/v2` and check the `args` property for the above endpoints. For example, using your browser *console*, run `fetch( '/wp-json/wp/v2' ).then( res => res.json() ).then( data => console.log( data ) )` while viewing your site's homepage or maybe an admin page, and you'd see something like so for the menu items endpoint:

  [image: Preview image]

  Or in the above case where the endpoint index is `0`, this JS will easily show you the arguments..

  `fetch( '/wp-json/wp/v2' ).then( res => res.json() ).then( data => console.log( data.routes['/wp/v2/menu-items'].endpoints[0].args ) )`

**Examples:**

- `getMenu( 449 )` — get the data (a menu object like the one in your post) for the menu with the ID 449
- `getMenuItem( 456 )` — get the data (a menu item object) for the menu item with the ID 456
- `getMenuItems( { menus: 449 } )` — get the menu items for the menu with the ID 449
- `getMenus( { search: 'legal' } )` — search for a menu where for example the title contains `legal`